# Neither able to boot ubuntu 20.04, nor able to reinstall from live usb

Tags: boot, bios, bootloader, ubuntu-core, grub-efi

I am new to linux. I just baught Dell Vostro 15 3580 and I had windows 10 installed on it. I installed ubuntu 20.04 from usb. But now whenever I start my laptop , in first attempt the Dell logo doesn't disappear, and for next attempts Grub screen appears. When I select ubuntu, only a black screen appears(with NO blinking cursor in it). If I select from linux kernal option, the boot hangs at "loading ramdisk....." line (same happens for recovery mode). However, if i plug charger into my laptop before starting laptop, ubuntu loads without any problem.

Then I tried to install ubuntu 18.04. However, when I choose any option (like install , or try without install), then the screen goes off and laptop starts restarting again and again.
Are there any solutions?

Note- the bios version is 1.4.1. and there is no PPT security option to be disabled in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have BIOS 1.4.1.

Current BIOS is 1.9.0 and can be downloaded from [here](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/product-support/product/vostro-15-3580-laptop/drivers).

Follow the procedures listed [here](https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/us/en/04/vostro-15-3580-laptop/vostro_3580_servicemanual/flashing-bios-usb-key?guid=guid-060d210f-c287-462b-ac38-81183d440a9d).

Comment: Thanks. I will try it. And will definitely mark your answer as accepted if it works.

Comment: Thanks sir. It worked perfectly.

Comment: @GurbirSingh Thanks for the update!